# PhoneGap get custom preference value

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-preferences

I'm just wondering how is it possible to read from JS a value stored in config.xml?

```
<preference name="MyCustomKey" value="MyValue" />
```

For example, I need to get this custom preference using something like:

```
console.log(cordova.preferences.MyCustomKey);
```

I've found something similar [for IOS only](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/iOS/ApplicationPreferences), but I'd like to have a cross-platform solution.

Thank you in advance.